# How do I iterate a counter and include it in a string replacement? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, loops, str-replace

I am using Python 3.6. I have a source file (txt) which has had `<s></s>` tags added to each sentence. The source file may have several hundred sentences in it. (I will have many such source files, but right now I’m working on just one.) I want to search the text, find each occurrence of `<s>` and replace it with `<s n="x">` where `x` is a counter starting at 1 and each sentence has a sequential number for `x` in the `n="x"` attribute. The finished text should look like this:

`<s n="1">This is the first sentence. </s><s n="2">This is the second sentence. </s> … <s n="nth">This is the nth sentence.</s>`

I only need to change the number in the opening tag, this has nothing to do with the text in the sentences.

I want to do something like this:

```
file_handle = open(file, 'r')
file_string = file_handle.read()
file_handle.close()

for counter, '<s>' in file_string:
    file_string = file_string.replace('<s>', '<s n="' + str(counter) + '">')
```

I know the first three lines are not Pythonic, but they serve their purpose in this context (meaning getting to a string). If I should be working with something other than a string, then the first three lines need to change. The problem is that nothing I have tried results in the counter moving to counter+1 for each successive instance of `<s>` in file_string. The best I have gotten is that every sentence has `<s n="1">` as the opening tag.

I have tried various combinations of enumerate, replace, re.sub, match, and I’m facing the classic “this is easy but I don’t see it” problem of a newbie. None of the searches I have done have turned up this embedded counter concept.

How can I accomplish this simple task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a preliminary, I create `some_text` similar to what you might have.

```
>>> some_text = 50*'<s>One sentence</s>'
>>> some_text
'<s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s><s>One sentence</s>'
```

Now I can use a regular expression to identify each `<s>` string and then invoke its `.sub` method to substitute whatever the `do_it` function `return`s in place of that string.

```
>>> n = 0
>>> import re
>>> def do_it(matchobj):
...     global n
...     n+=1
...     return '<s n="%s">'%n
... 
>>> re.sub(r'<s>', do_it, some_text)
'<s n="1">One sentence</s><s n="2">One sentence</s><s n="3">One sentence</s><s n="4">One sentence</s><s n="5">One sentence</s><s n="6">One sentence</s><s n="7">One sentence</s><s n="8">One sentence</s><s n="9">One sentence</s><s n="10">One sentence</s><s n="11">One sentence</s><s n="12">One sentence</s><s n="13">One sentence</s><s n="14">One sentence</s><s n="15">One sentence</s><s n="16">One sentence</s><s n="17">One sentence</s><s n="18">One sentence</s><s n="19">One sentence</s><s n="20">One sentence</s><s n="21">One sentence</s><s n="22">One sentence</s><s n="23">One sentence</s><s n="24">One sentence</s><s n="25">One sentence</s><s n="26">One sentence</s><s n="27">One sentence</s><s n="28">One sentence</s><s n="29">One sentence</s><s n="30">One sentence</s><s n="31">One sentence</s><s n="32">One sentence</s><s n="33">One sentence</s><s n="34">One sentence</s><s n="35">One sentence</s><s n="36">One sentence</s><s n="37">One sentence</s><s n="38">One sentence</s><s n="39">One sentence</s><s n="40">One sentence</s><s n="41">One sentence</s><s n="42">One sentence</s><s n="43">One sentence</s><s n="44">One sentence</s><s n="45">One sentence</s><s n="46">One sentence</s><s n="47">One sentence</s><s n="48">One sentence</s><s n="49">One sentence</s><s n="50">One sentence</s>'
```

Comment: That works, though I did have to add back the "" around the %s as they are needed for the XML tagging I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: @kgrady: Would you do me the courtesy of accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry, thought I had! My bad.

Comment: No worries. I like them, it's part of the etiquette of SO, and it saves others answering unless there's something inadequate about my answer.

Comment: I agree, which is why it is embarrassing to have not checked that I did it. Bad form!

Comment: Corrected in response to your comment.